# Cannot get Bigquery dynamic sql results in a connected sheet or Looker studio

Tags: google-bigquery

here is my query:

```
DECLARE month_ string;

EXECUTE IMMEDIATE """select STRING_AGG(CONCAT("'",formatted_date_string,"'")) AS formatted_date_string from (select distinct FORMAT_DATE('%Y-%m-%d', trunc_month) AS formatted_date_string from production_data.feb_2024_overall_feature_usage order by formatted_date_string)""" INTO month_;

select month_;

EXECUTE IMMEDIATE format(""" 
select * from production_data.feb_2024_overall_feature_usage
PIVOT(Sum(total_distinct_users) FOR trunc_month IN (%s))""",month_);
```

the results show up fine in bigquery, but I want to view the results in either a connected sheet or looker studio. Whenever I try pasting this code in either a connected sheet, or looker studio - it throws an error. Nor can I create a view around this code and call that view in connected sheets. Any ideas are welcome, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

UPDATE: I managed to solve it! here is the code,

```
DECLARE month_ STRING;

-- Retrieve distinct month values and store them in month_ variable

EXECUTE IMMEDIATE '''

SELECT STRING_AGG(CONCAT("'", formatted_date_string, "'")) AS formatted_date_string

FROM (

SELECT DISTINCT FORMAT_DATE('%Y-%m-%d', trunc_month) AS formatted_date_string

FROM production_data.feb_2024_overall_feature_usage

ORDER BY formatted_date_string

)

''' INTO month_;

-- Dynamically create the view using the retrieved month values

EXECUTE IMMEDIATE FORMAT('''

CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW dn-app.production_data.boto AS

SELECT *

FROM (

SELECT * FROM production_data.feb_2024_overall_feature_usage

)

PIVOT (

SUM(total_distinct_users) FOR trunc_month IN (%s)

)

''', month_);
```

---

the view dn-app.production_data.boto has the final results. This view is visible on connected google sheets.